Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException .NET MAUI
After installing BarcodeScanner.Mobile version 8.0.0.1 I get this exception when the application starts: MAUI Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).'
Does anyone got the same experience?

In your Android project in MainActivity, what does the ActivityAttbitute look like?

@Cheesebaron I don't have any attribute:
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]

@Cheesebaron using the default maui splash screen theme

I don't know which part of my app requires an Material design but this is what I do to fix this crash:

In Platform/Android/Resources/values added styles.xml and inside added this code:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   </style>
</resources>


Make styles.xml Build Action AndroidResource
In AndroidManifest.xml in the <manifest> tag added this lines of code:xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:replace="android:theme"
In MainActivity.cs replace the Theme attribute property like this:
[Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme"....)]

All this changes fixed my problem with the Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException
